# The arduino is skipping the if statement and just running the whole cod continuously i could not figure out how to fix it

Tags: if-statement, logic, logical-operators, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

My problem is that I am making an alarm that goes off when the temperature is greater than a preset amount. however the Arduino is going past the if statement and not stopping at the gate.
I have tried looking up different syntax however it keeps going through the if statement like it is not there while it still serial prints.

```
//naming the led's left to right defining the pin and the constant int
//coded by luke
// the breadboard has 6 leds lined up by order 1,2,3,4,5,6 on the corresponding pins
//6.28.2014
// second program written from scratch
// !buzzer pin 8!
// integers
const int led1=(1);
const int led2=(2);
const int led3=(3);
const int led4=(4);
const int led5=(5);
const int led6=(6);
const int buzzer=(8);
const int temp=(0);
int maxtemp=(80);


// place the buzzer at pin 8 for sound

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(temp, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    delay (1000);
    analogRead(temp);
    delay (100);
    Serial.print(analogRead(temp)/2.05);
    delay (10);
    if(analogRead(temp/2.05) > maxtemp)
    {
        tone (buzzer, 440);
        delay (100); // wait to turn on the second
        digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led3, HIGH);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led2, LOW);
        delay (100);
        tone (buzzer, 450);
        digitalWrite (led4, HIGH);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led3, LOW);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led5, HIGH);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led4, LOW);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led6, HIGH);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led5, LOW);
        delay (100);
        digitalWrite (led6, LOW);
    }
}

// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're printing to serial is not the same as what you're comparing to `maxtemp` in the if statement:

```
Serial.print(analogRead(temp)/2.05);

if(analogRead(temp/2.05) > maxtemp)
```

The former has `/2.05` outside the `analogRead` call, the latter has it inside.  Assuming the former is reporting what you expect to see, changing the if statement to:

```
if((analogRead(temp) / 2.05) > maxtemp)
```

Should fix the problem.